# Could someone help me understand the grammar of the sentences

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, syntactic-analysis

It doesn't make sense to me every time I come across some sentences like the following one that I manage to make up now.

> Why should you be concerned about such a fuss? They are nothing more than a waste of breath.

So, really my confusion is that I don't see the point in pluralising the object which has been mentioned immediately before the same sentence.

Comment: Can you find a “real language” example from a native speaker? Your example is not idiomatic. For instance, the verb phrase in the first sentence should be _be concerned about_ or concern yourself with_.

Comment: @KarlG Done. It's an improvement, but I'm not entirely sure it's quite idiomatic yet though — the disconnect between the singular *fuss* and *They* is something idiomatic English would tend to avoid, I think, even when expressing a generality.

Comment: @Andrew Leach. Since I don't get the sense of real english", how can I reword the example according to you idea? And could you give me some examples like this, as I can't find any other fine examples relating to my question at this moment.

Comment: Use _it_, not _they_. _They_ has no referent, but _it_ refers to _fuss_.